# Vue.js Axios - router.push doesn't redirect

Tags: vue.js

I have an Axios get call that if encountered with an error and doesn't redirect user to the desired route.  Here is the scenario:

1. User lands on a blog list which is created by her. mydomain/bloglist
2. User then clicks on the link of the individual blog and goes to the detail blog post page. The each blog has a unique id e.g 35 and users can view only their own posts. mydomain/blogdetail/35
3. User decides to do something bad i.e. looking into someone else's posts.  User replaces 35 with 45.   User is redirected back to his blog list, but that is not happening.  Instead, I see mydomain/blogdetail/bloglist and an empty page with the header footer and body.  I tried if and else statements but no avail.

Below is my code:

```
}).catch(error => {
  console.log('something wrong happened' + error);
  this.$router.push('bloglist')
}
```

All the routes are setup ok otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried `this.$router.push('/bloglist')`? Personally, I prefer [named routes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/named-routes.html) so you don't have to worry about paths

Comment: Just did. Thank you.  I am new to Vue.  Switched from Angular JS therefore a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can using like that

```js
this.$router.push({
  url: '/bloglist'
})
```

[See more information](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)